# How do I do inheritance in APACHE AGE

Tags: apache-age

Is Inheritance possible in apache age, I have used this to install apache age. I have a graph to implement, and there are inheritance relations also. How would I implement those. E.g I have a parent and a child nodes. I want the child to inherit the parent. Is it possible, and if yes then how so. I have looked that there is a inheritance branch, but i dont know how inheritance works in the branch.

It uses the create_vlabel and create_elabel. How are they used?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a label for the parent node (vertex) using the following command:

```
SELECT create_vlabel('age_graph', 'PARENT_LABEL');
```

Then, you can create a label for the child node with the parent label included in its array using the following command:

```
SELECT create_vlabel('age_graph', 'CHILD_LABEL', ARRAY['PARENT_LABEL']);
```

Another way to implement this in Apache AGE is through edge label inheritance. You can do this with the following queries:

```
SELECT create_elabel('age_graph', 'PARENT_EDGE');
SELECT create_elabel('age_graph', 'CHILD_EDGE_A', ARRAY['PARENT_EDGE']);
SELECT create_elabel('age_graph', 'CHILD_EDGE_B', ARRAY['CHILD_EDGE_A']);
```

Note that a child edge can also serve as the parent edge for another edge in this implementation

After creating the labels, you just need to use it when creating your vertex or edge:

```
-- Vertex label inheritance
SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$
    CREATE (n:PARENT_LABEL {}) 
    RETURN n
$$) AS (n agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$
    CREATE (n:CHILD_LABEL {}) 
    RETURN n
$$) AS (n agtype);

-- Edge label inheritance
SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$
    CREATE (:vertex)-[e:PARENT_EDGE]->(:vertex) 
    RETURN e
$$) AS (e agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$
    CREATE (:vertex)-[e:CHILD_EDGE]->(:vertex) 
    RETURN e
$$) AS (e agtype);
```